# Invalid Subelement Phone_ExtensionStr-urn:com.workday/bsvc for element Phone_Information_Data workday

Tags: servicenow, workday-api

I am trying to add a phone number(with phone extension) in the contact details in Workday through REST api.

My phone details object looks like this:

```
 "Phone Details": [
    {
        "Area_Code": null,
        "Country_ISO_Code": null,
        "Delete": false,
        "Do_Not_Replace_All": true,
        "ID": null,
        "International_Phone_Code": "1",
        "Phone_Device_Type_Reference_ID": "telephone",
        "Phone_Extension": 123,
        "Phone_Number": "1234567890",
        "Phone_Reference_ID": null,
        "Usage_Details": [
            {
                "Comments": null,
                "Is_Primary": true,
                "Public": true,
                "Type_Reference_ID": "Work",
                "Use_For_Reference_ID": null,
                "Use_For_Tenanted_Reference_ID": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I got an error: **Invalid Subelement Phone_ExtensionStr-urn:com.workday/bsvc for element Phone_Information_Data workday**

Is there something wrong with the format that i have for my "Phone_Extension"?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: Issue is with the script that transformed JSON -> XML, instead of **Phone_Extension** it is using **Phone_ExtensionStr**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).